# How to infer imported method names from IOS Mach-O binary

Tags: ios, macos, linker, mach-o, dyld

When using a disassembler to analyze IOS binaries (Mach-O) files, I see that method names are annotated for functions in external libraries, even for C-style function calls in release binaries.  I have been reading up on the Mach-O file format but am having trouble finding out to match up up the __stub_helper entries with the function names, and the names don't appear to be stored in the binary itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - the information is stored in LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY->lazy_bind_off. See the comments in this question for more details:

[Mach-O symbol stubs (IOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825537/mach-o-symbol-stubs-ios)